# Why is this an infinite loop in java?

Tags: java

I can't use any other math symbols than ++ -- > < = and I am having trouble figuring out why this is an infinite loop.

```
 while (d < n)
    {

        System.out.print(d + "  ");
        for (count = 0 ; count < d ; count++)
        {
        d++;
        }
        for (count = d; count > 0; count--)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're increasing d and count by the same amount in every iteration. So count will never be less than d.

Comment: What's the data type of `d`?  The answer is different if `d` is an integer type, than if it's a floating type.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `d` and `n` are both of type `int`, and that the outer loop is actually iterated at all.

Case 1 - if `d` is initially zero or negative, then neither of the `for` loops will iterate at all.  Therefore, `d` will never change, so `d < n` can't stop being true.  The `while` loop will therefore never end.

Case 2 - if `d` is positive, then on the first iteration of the `while` loop, the first `for` loop increases both `count` and `d` at the same time.  The `for` condition will continue to run until `d` achieves  integer overflow and becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  The `for` loop then exits.  But then, the second iteration of the `while` loop is just like case 1 - it won't end.

Answer (score 0):

because you change d in the loop..since d is always increasing you are never going to escape the loop

Comment: No, that's only half the story.  If `d` is `int`, it will overflow fairly quickly, and the inner loop will end when it gets to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  The problem is that it will then be less than `n`, so we can't escape the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in while block but

```
for (count = 0 ; count < d ; count++)
{
    d++;
}
```

this `for` block is bad. if `d` is already bigger then `count` it becomes an infinite loop. say d=2 and count=0. Second loop `d=3`, `count=1`. Third loop `d=4`, `count=2` and it goes on like that.

Comment: Until you get integer overflow.  Then it gets interesting!

Comment: Yes but it's another long long and deep story if you want to explain.

Comment: Well, yes, I've done so.  It's not that long a story.  Your answer isn't really the truth - the `for` loop doesn't go on forever, if `d` is `int` or `long`.